# Using expectEvent with hardhat requires an argument of type `never`

Tags: typescript, ethereum, smartcontracts, hardhat

When I make a contract call with hardhat

```
const resp0 = await collateralPool.selfCloseExit(tokenShare0, true, TokenExitType.MINIMIZE_FEE_DEBT, "", { from: accounts[0] });
```

I get that this has the type `const resp0: Truffle.TransactionResponse<never>`. Now when I want to test whether an event was triggered, I use

```
expectEvent(resp0, "AgentRedemptionInCollateral", { _amountUBA: fassets0 });
```

but it tells me the argument "AgentRedemptionInCollateral" is expected to be of type `never`. How can I fix this? The `expectEvent` is imported as

```
import { expectEvent } from "@openzeppelin/test-helpers";
```

Is it a problem that a function emitting an event is in another contract that is getting called by collateralPool.

Answer (score 1):

When searching online I found that other people are also experiencing problems with this package in typescript I think the easiest way to fix this is by adding `// @ts-ignore` or by calling the function like `(expectEvent as any)(resp0, "AgentRedemptionInCollateral, { _amountUBA: fassets0 });`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that the event was triggered in a different contract, through the one that was called initially. Using method `expectEvent.inTransaction` solved the problem.